# How to stream tweets using tweepy from a start date to end date using python?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, twitter-streaming-api, mining

I am currently in the process of doing some research using sentiment analysis on twitter data regarding a certain topic (isn't necessarily important to this question) using python, of which I am a beginner at. I understand the twitter streaming API limits users to access only to the previous 7 days unless you apply for a full enterprise search which opens up the whole archive. I had recently been given access to the full archive for this research project from twitter but I am unable to specify a start and end date to the tweets I would like to stream into a csv file. This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener


ckey = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
csecret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
atoken = 'xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
asecret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'


# =============================================================================
# def sentimentAnalysis(text):
#     output = '0'
#     return output
# =============================================================================

class listener(StreamListener):
    def on_data(self, data):
        tweet = data.split(',"text":"')[1].split('","source')[0]
        saveMe = tweet+'::'+'\n'
        output = open('output.csv','a')
        output.write(saveMe)
        output.close()
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)

auth = OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)
twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener())
twitterStream.filter(track=["#weather"], languages = ["en"])
```

Now this code streams twitter date from the past 7 days perfectly. I tried changing the bottom line to

```
twitterStream.filter(track=["#weather"], languages = ["en"], since = ["2016-06-01"])
```

but this returns this error :: filter() got an unexpected keyword argument 'since'.

What would be the correct way to filter by a given date frame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tweepy does not provide the "since" argument, as you can check yourself [here](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/c8e473ed7b939e09a485d0eaa2390554f009a56b/tweepy/streaming.py#L426).

To achieve the desired output, you will have to use the `api.user_timeline`, iterating through pages until the desired date is reached, Eg:

```
import tweepy
import datetime

# The consumer keys can be found on your application's Details
# page located at https://dev.twitter.com/apps (under "OAuth settings")
consumer_key=""
consumer_secret=""

# The access tokens can be found on your applications's Details
# page located at https://dev.twitter.com/apps (located
# under "Your access token")
access_token=""
access_token_secret=""

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)
page = 1
stop_loop = False
while not stop_loop:
    tweets = api.user_timeline(username, page=page)
    if not tweets:
        break
    for tweet in tweets:
        if datetime.date(YEAR, MONTH, DAY) < tweet.created_at:
            stop_loop = True
            break
        # Do the tweet process here
    page+=1
    time.sleep(500)
```

*Note that you will need to update the code to fit your needs, this is just a general solution.*

Comment: So i have to iterate through the pages and only add to the csv file for when the date time matches my specified values? Oh makes sense. On another note, do you know how to specify for locations?

Comment: [In this link](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/c8e473ed7b939e09a485d0eaa2390554f009a56b/tweepy/streaming.py#L426) you can check all the arguments that the function might accept. Locations is one of them :p